# Javafx Tutorial 4 Will Not Compile

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, javafx, classnotfoundexception

[Here is the tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm)

I have been following the tutorials for javafx using e(fx)clipse and I cannot get this one to launch. My code is exactly the same as their's is and it works if I use Netbeans, but I am getting this error with eclipse:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fxmlexample.FXMLExampleController
/C:/Users/Michael/workspace/JavaFX%20Test/bin/fxmltest/fxml_example.fxml:10
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:726)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:775)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:180)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:563)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2314)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2131)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2744)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2709)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2696)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
  at fxmltest.FXMLExample.start(FXMLExample.java:17)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fxmlexample.FXMLExampleController
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:726)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:775)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:180)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:563)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2314)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2131)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2709)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2696)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
    at fxmltest.FXMLExample.start(FXMLExample.java:17)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fxmlexample.FXMLExampleController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:724)
    ... 22 more
```

Anyone have any solutions to get this to work with eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out what I did wrong. Netbeans automatically creates a package named what your projects name is, so when I added the controller `fxmlexample.FXMLExampleController` it was looking in the package `fxmlexample`, which I was just using the default package.

Simply creating a package called `fxmlexample` and moving my files into there fixed it.